# Recursive definition of the (!!)-function

Tags: haskell, recursion

So I tried to build the (!!) function as already defined in GHC.List recursively.
I want to extract the n-th element of a list and return that.
Here's what I got first:

```
taken0 :: [β] -> Int -> β -- but not recursive
βs `taken0` 0 = head βs
βs `taken0` n = last (take (n+1) βs)
```

This worked, but it wasn't recursive...

then I tried the following:

```
taken :: [γ] -> Int -> γ -- doesn't compile
taken γs 0 = head γs
taken γs 1 = head (tail γs)
taken γs n = head ( tail (takenth γs (n-1)) )
```

After some fixing I ended up with this:

```
taken :: [γ] -> Int -> [γ] -- works, but returns a list
taken γs 0 = γs
taken γs 1 = tail γs
taken γs n = tail (taken γs (n-1))
```

Which does indeed compile but is ugly to handle, it returns a list whoose first element is that one "entered" by n.

```
*Main> head ([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] `taken` 0)      returns 0
*Main> head ([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] `taken` 1)      returns 1
*Main> head ([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] `taken` 2)      returns 2
etc.
```

Always returns the right (n-th element)
but I had to insert head before.

What I want is a function, which, although recursive, returns a single element instead of a list...
Is there a way to accomplish this without writing another function or using head everytime ?
like:

```
*Main> taken2 [5,8,6,0,2,5,7] 3                    returns 0
```

thanks in advance !

Comment: As you see, changing the type signature doesn't solve the problem. As a general rule, you should only change the type of a function if you determine that the type is in fact incorrect. In this case, you know you want to return `y`, not `[y]`, so changing the type is not the right solution. Instead, you should figure out what the error message is telling you is wrong. Haskell errors are very intimidating to start. Feel free to post the error when you ask a question here and members of the community will help explain what it means.

Comment: Prefer pattern-matching to using `head` and `tail`.

Comment: Incidentally, your `taken :: [γ] -> Int -> [γ]` version has another name in the Prelude - it's `flip drop`. `drop` is the complement of `take`, and the combination is done by `splitAt`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing a recursive function on lists, you should almost always start by mirroring the recursive definition of the list type itself: a case for empty lists, and a case for a cons pair:

```
taken :: [γ] -> Int -> γ
taken [] n = _
taken (γ:γs) n = _
```

Note, the above syntax with underscore placeholders is actual Haskell syntax (for recent enough GHC), which will cause the compiler to print out errors like this asking you to fill in the blanks, and telling you about the pieces you have available to fill them in:

```
foo.hs:2:14: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: γ
      Where: ‘γ’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for:
                 taken :: forall γ. [γ] -> Int -> γ
               at foo.hs:1:1-24
    • In the expression: _
      In an equation for ‘taken’: taken [] n = _
    • Relevant bindings include
        n :: Int (bound at foo.hs:2:10)
        taken :: [γ] -> Int -> γ (bound at foo.hs:2:1)
  |
2 | taken [] n = _
  |              ^

foo.hs:3:18: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: γ
      Where: ‘γ’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for:
                 taken :: forall γ. [γ] -> Int -> γ
               at foo.hs:1:1-24
    • In the expression: _
      In an equation for ‘taken’: taken (γ : γs) n = _
    • Relevant bindings include
        n :: Int (bound at foo.hs:3:14)
        γs :: [γ] (bound at foo.hs:3:10)
        γ :: γ (bound at foo.hs:3:8)
        taken :: [γ] -> Int -> γ (bound at foo.hs:2:1)
  |
3 | taken (γ:γs) n = _
  |
```

So the first hole we need to fill in is of type `γ`. However the only things we have available are the `Int` `n`, and making a recursive call to `taken`. Since the list is empty, recursing isn't going to help us; it'll just end up back at the same case we're in. And thinking about what our function is supposed to do, we can't get the `n`th element of an empty list no matter what `n` is. So we'll need to just call `error` here.

```
taken :: [γ] -> Int -> γ
taken [] n = error "Index out of range"
taken (γ:γs) n = _
```

The second hole is also of type `γ`, and GHC tells us:

```
• Relevant bindings include
    n :: Int (bound at foo.hs:3:14)
    γs :: [γ] (bound at foo.hs:3:10)
    γ :: γ (bound at foo.hs:3:8)
    taken :: [γ] -> Int -> γ (bound at foo.hs:2:1)
```

So we can obviously just use `γ` to appease the type checker, but logically which value we return should depend on `n`. If we're taking the 0th element of this list, well we've already got the head element decomposed as value `γ` due to our pattern match, so that'll be correct in that case. Lets try:

```
taken :: [γ] -> Int -> γ
taken [] n = error "Index out of range"
taken (γ:γs) n
  | n == 0    = γ
  | otherwise = _
```

Which gives us:

```
foo.hs:5:17: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: γ
      Where: ‘γ’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for:
                 taken :: forall γ. [γ] -> Int -> γ
               at foo.hs:1:1-24
    • In the expression: _
      In an equation for ‘taken’:
          taken (γ : γs) n
            | n == 0 = γ
            | otherwise = _
    • Relevant bindings include
        n :: Int (bound at foo.hs:3:14)
        γs :: [γ] (bound at foo.hs:3:10)
        γ :: γ (bound at foo.hs:3:8)
        taken :: [γ] -> Int -> γ (bound at foo.hs:2:1)
  |
5 |   | otherwise = _
  |
```

Same type of hole, same relevant bindings available. But we know that `γ` isn't the right answer, since we've already handled the case when it is. The answer we *do* want to return should be somewhere in `γs`, and we know we want to write this function recursively, so the obvious thing to do is insert a recursive call:

```
taken :: [γ] -> Int -> γ
taken [] n = error "Index out of range"
taken (γ:γs) n
  | n == 0    = γ
  | otherwise = taken γs _

foo.hs:5:26: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: Int
    • In the second argument of ‘taken’, namely ‘_’
      In the expression: taken γs _
      In an equation for ‘taken’:
          taken (γ : γs) n
            | n == 0 = γ
            | otherwise = taken γs _
    • Relevant bindings include
        n :: Int (bound at foo.hs:3:14)
        γs :: [γ] (bound at foo.hs:3:10)
        γ :: γ (bound at foo.hs:3:8)
        taken :: [γ] -> Int -> γ (bound at foo.hs:2:1)
  |
5 |   | otherwise = taken γs _
  |
```

Now we're getting somewhere. The remaining hole is of type `Int`, and we have `n :: Int` available. Plugging that straight in is tempting, but doesn't make sense if we stop to think about what we're doing. Taking the `n`th element of the list `(γ:γs)` (which is the result we're supposed to be returning) when `n \= 0` should be the same as taking the `(n - 1)`th element of `γs`, so:

```
taken :: [γ] -> Int -> γ
taken [] n = error "Index out of range"
taken (γ:γs) n
  | n == 0    = γ
  | otherwise = taken γs (n - 1)
```

No more holes! And this actually works. The only problem is that we don't handle negative values of `n`. It turns out that's actually sortof okay; for finite lists we eventually run off the end and hit the `error "Index out of range"` case, which is accurate. But it would be nicer to fail before iterating the whole list. So:

```
taken :: [γ] -> Int -> γ
taken [] n = error "Index out of range"
taken (γ:γs) n
  | n == 0    = γ
  | n < 0     = error "Negative index"
  | otherwise = taken γs (n - 1)
```

I highly recommend this "hole driven development" style (whether you use actual hole syntax and get GHC to typecheck them or just do it yourself as you write the code). Let the structure of the types you're using guide the "shape" of the function you're writing (e.g. when writing a function on lists, use a case for `[]` and a case for `(x:xs)`), and then fill in the holes one at a time. Sometimes you'l need a different structure than this guides you towards, but very often not, and even when you do having started this approach and found out what the problems are gives you much better information for guessing the right structure.

Answer (score 7):

```
taken :: [γ] -> Int -> [γ] -- works, but returns a list
taken γs 0 = γs
taken γs 1 = tail γs
taken γs n = tail (taken γs (n-1))
```

This is very close. There are three problems:

1. You have too many cases. You only need these two:

   ```
   taken ys 0 = ...
   taken ys n = ...
   ```
2. You want to return an element of the list, not a list. In particular, the first rule needs to return the first element of the list. One way to do this is with `head`:

   ```
   taken ys 0 = head ys
   ```
3. Now we need to fix the second rule. We want to write this recursively, so we want to do something like this:

   ```
   taken ys n = taken ?? ??
   ```

   What do we put in place of the `??`s? Well, we know that `n` is at least `1`. And if we get down to `0`, we can use the first rule to return the result. This suggests that the second parameter should be `(n-1)` as you already have tried.

   We also know that the first element of `ys` isn't the right one to use, so we want to throw it away. To do this, we can use `tail ys`. Putting this all together we get

   ```
   taken ys n = taken (tail ys) (n-1)
   ```

So it seems that the main mistake here is you were applying `tail` in the wrong place.

**Notes**

1. This solution isn't robust. It will cause an infinite recursion if you call it with a negative index. Handling for this case is left as an exercise for the reader.
2. You can use pattern matching instead of `head` and `tail`. For example, the first case can be written as

   ```
   taken (y:_) 0 = y
   ```

   I leave implementing the second case with pattern matching as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a straightforward one is:

```
nth0 :: [a] -> Int -> a
nth0 (x:xs) i | i >= 1 = nth0 xs (i-1)
              | i < 0 = error "Index less than zero"
              | otherwise = x
nth0 [] i = error "Index too large"
```

So the recursive part is the `nth0 xs (i-1)`. Here we thus perform recursion on the tail of the list `xs`, and with a decremented index `i-1`.

The base case is the `otherwise` (which fires in case `i == 0`), in which case we return the head of the list `x`.

The remaining cases cover the fact that the index could be negative, or that the index is greater than, or equal to the length of the list.